# jQuery + django sending ordered list of numbers

Tags: jquery, django, url, parameters, url-parameters

I have a simple task list that the user can choose how to order.
When the user order the tasks I want to send all the tasks' IDs **in their order** to the server.
In short, what is the most convenient to send a javascript array and fetch the values in django view?

If I do this:

```
// tasks is an array of numbers, e.g [1,2,3,4]
$.post('/save_tasks/', {tasks: tasks}).done(...)
```

then I can access them in the view with
 `request.POST.getlist('tasks[]')`
But this does not guarantee the order.

Answer (score 0):

I will convert array list to String.

```
$.post('/save_tasks/', {tasks: tasks.toString()}).done(...)
```

In view.py

```
def yourview(request):
    _get_task_list = request.POST['tasks']
    # and do something like string.split, it will be more convenient.
```

I use this way to send the list, hope it can help.